# gtsummary in Survey analysis (labels get lost when using subset function of survey)

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary

**Labels of variables (using Labelled package) do not carry over when subsetting the survey using (subset of Survey package), and I end up having to manually insert labels into the gtsummary function.**

```
library(dplyr)
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)
library(labelled)

#Reading the CSV file (please download a sample dataframe from link below) 
df <- read.csv("nis_2.csv")

#Change to factors 
names <- c("htn", "dm", "FEMALE")
df[, names] <- lapply(included_df[, names], factor)

#Changing labels 
var_label(df$AGE) <- "Age"
var_label(df$FEMALE) <- "Gender (Female)"
var_label(df$dm) <- "Diabetes"
var_label(df$htn) <- "Hypertension"

#declare survey design 
dstr <- svydesign(
 id = ~HOSP_NIS, 
 strata = ~NIS_STRATUM, 
 weights = ~DISCWT, 
 nest=TRUE, 
 survey.lonely.psu = "adjust",  
 data = df)

#subset the data to include our UGIB cirrhotics 
small_set <- subset(dstr, (htn == 1))
summary(small_set)

small_set %>%
  tbl_svysummary(
   by=dm,
   include = c(AGE, FEMALE),
   missing = "no", 
   statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) %>%
  add_p() %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Patient Characteristics**") %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**History of Diabetes**")
```

Sample database at: https://github.com/Dr-Kaboum/nis_gt_summary/blob/16909872624714d1feb30bd501a6204aba947de7/nis_2.csv

Comment: does `subset()` remove the label attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset` removes the labelled attributes, subset your data first, label it, and then pass to `gtsummary`

```
#example of the label being removed. 
library(labelled)


var_label(mtcars$mpg) <- "Mile per gallon"

mt2 <- subset(mtcars, cyl == 4)
var_label(mt2$mpg) <- "Mile per gallon" #need to relabel
```

### edit using `var_label()` on subset of survey object

I can't access your data but using an example set, I show that you can relabel the data when you access the `variables` part of the survey object list. If you label there it will show up in the table.

```
# A dataset with a complex design
library(gtsummary)
data(api, package = "survey")
labelled::var_label(apiclus1$api99) <- "API 99"

survdat <-
  survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) 
#this subset will remove labels
survdat2 <- subset(survdat, (cname == "Fresno"))
#relabel here after subset within survey object
labelled::var_label(survdat2$variables$api99) <- "API 99"

#make table with label
ex<-  tbl_svysummary(data = survdat2,by = "both", include = c(cname, api00, api99, both))
```

Comment: I agree that the subset seems to drop the label attribute, but I cannot use var_label on a subset of a survey object.

Comment: can you use `dplyr::filter()` instead that seems to keep the label. Why can't you filter the data first and then create the survey object?

Comment: Because of the sampling weights. They are better managed through the subset function of the survey package. "If the data set is subset (meaning that observations not to be included in the subpopulation are deleted from the data set), the standard errors of the estimates cannot be calculated correctly".

Comment: @crytpodoc I updated with an example of how to label a survey object after a subset.

Comment: It worked! Appreciate it !